# Replace backSlash '\' with a normal slash '/' in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi guys I have an imageUrl with backSlashes('\\') I want to replaceAll the backSlashes with a normal slash ('/')

this is an imageUrl example :
**public\images\providerProfilePictures\2022-04-04T19-08-50.943Z-scaled_image_picker8914175492511161913.jpg**

I want to make it with normal slashes like this one :
**public/images/providerProfilePictures/2022-04-04T19-08-50.943Z-scaled_image_picker8914175492511161913.jpg**

this is my code :

```
 path = decoded['profilePictureUrl'];
  if (path!=''){
    path.replaceAll('/', '\\');
    path=ApiConstants.BASE_URL+path;

    print(" my path now : "+path);
```

I'm getting a wrong result with this function any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got the 2 parameters swapped.

You have:

```
path.replaceAll('/', '\\');
```

It should be:

```
path.replaceAll('\\', '/');
```

Unrelated, but instead of `if (path!='')` you could write `if (path.isNotEmpty)` for improved readability.

Also, you can use the letter `r` in front of a String to make it verbatim.

---

Try this:

```
  final s = r'public\images\providerProfilePictures\2022-04-04T19-08-50.943Z-scaled_image_picker8914175492511161913.jpg';
  final url = s.replaceAll('\\', '/');
  print(url);
```

Console output:

> flutter:
> public/images/providerProfilePictures/2022-04-04T19-08-50.943Z-scaled_image_picker8914175492511161913.jpg

Comment: The issue is when you put only one backslash like this one ('\') the editor is returning an Unterminated string literal if you try this yourself you will find out what I'm talking about

Comment: @Selim Yeah that's why you put 2 slashes like you already did. You just got the "from" and "to" parameters swapped, in the "replaceAll" function.